# Mongoose ignore specific value for object field in find()

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am doing a query for user accounts in MongoDB with mongoose and it is returning an array
of users with the same lastName and DOB.

However it is also returning the account for the current user, how can I tell Mongoose to ignore accounts with a specific objectId?

I need Mongoose to ***ignore req.body.userId*** for object-field **_id**

Thank you

```
// CHECK FOR DUPLICATE USER ACCOUNT
router.post("/api/verification/check-for-duplicate-user", auth, async 
(req, res) => {

    try {
      const duplicates = await User.find(
        { DOB: req.body.DOB, lastName: req.body.lastName },
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(`ERROR ${err}`)
          } else {
            console.log(`FOUND DUPLICATES`)
          }
        }
      )

      if (duplicates) {
        return res.send(duplicates)
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send()
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from mongodb site:
Syntax: {field: {$ne: value} }

so you need something like this:

```
User.find(
    { DOB: req.body.DOB, lastName: req.body.lastName, _id: {$ne: require('mongo').ObjectId(req.body.userId)} }
```